# Call function for column in datafame

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, tokenize, data-preprocessing

I've successfully imported these libraries

```
import pandas as pd
from underthesea import word_tokenize
```

and load data

```
df=pd.read_csv("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/BigData/BookingReview.csv")
print (df)
```

[image: here is image of data]

I tried to use function word_tokenize for the column named 'Review'

```
df['Review']=df['Review'].apply(word_tokenize)
```

but it show this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-386271f3d8ee> in <module>()
----> 1 df['Review']=df['Review'].apply(word_tokenize)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4211             else:
   4212                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4213                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4214 
   4215         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/underthesea/pipeline/word_tokenize/__init__.py in word_tokenize(sentence, format)
     32     'Bác_sĩ bây_giờ có_thể thản_nhiên báo_tin bệnh_nhân bị ung_thư'
     33     """
---> 34     tokens = tokenize(sentence)
     35     crf_model = CRFModel.instance()
     36     output = crf_model.predict(tokens, format)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/underthesea/pipeline/word_tokenize/regex_tokenize.py in tokenize(text, format, tag)
    233     :return: tokenize text
    234     """
--> 235     text = Text(text)
    236     text = text.replace("\t", " ")
    237     matches = [m for m in re.finditer(patterns, text)]

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/underthesea/feature_engineering/text.py in Text(text)
      9     """
     10     if not is_unicode(text):
---> 11         text = text.decode("utf-8")
     12     text = unicodedata.normalize("NFC", text)
     13     return text

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I used the function above to seperate word for sentiment analysing.
I've tried to found the answer for my problem and still don't know why this error occurs. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks all!

Comment: your problem is with the function `word_tokenize` and it's input, it's saying that some inputs to the function are floats... check your dataframe...

Comment: More specifically, `pandas` represents [missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html) with `np.NaN` which is technically of type `float64`. For this reason, you should handle the missing data first. Either by dropping rows with missing values, or by filling with empty string.